# EXC_BAD_ACCESS UITable set tableHeaderView in numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to set `tableHeaderView` in `numberOfRowsInSection`. But I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with no message in the output console.

Below is my `numberOfRowsInSection` function.

```
// number of rows in table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //SECTION 1
    if self.titles.count == 0 {
        self.noBookmarkView.alpha = 1.0
    }
    else {
        self.noBookmarkView.alpha = 0.0
    }
    //=====================================

    //SECTION 2
    if self.idsb.count != self.ids.count {
        self.bookmarkTableView.tableHeaderView = self.filteredView
    }
    else {
        self.bookmarkTableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    }
    //=====================================

    return self.titles.count
}
```

And below is my `viewDidLoad` where I initialize `filteredView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var noBookmarkView: UIView!
var filteredView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    filteredView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: bookmarkTableView.frame.width, height: 25))
    filteredView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.4, green: 0.4, blue: 0.71, alpha: 1.0)
    let label: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: filteredView.frame)
    label.text = "Filtered"
    label.font = UIFont.init(name: "System", size: 14.0)
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    filteredView.addSubview(label)
}
```

So before I added `filteredView` it worked perfectly with the `noBookmarkView`.

Now it has the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `self.noBookmarkView.alpha = 0.0`. If I comment out `SECTION 2` it works without errors. If I comment out `SECTION 1` it then has `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on line `self.bookmarkTableView.tableHeaderView = nil`.

I don't understand why it would fail on `self.noBookmarkView.alpha = 0.0` when it seems like `SECTION 2` is what is causing the problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't see the problem but I wonder if `noBookmarkView` being declared as weak is the problem. What else would be holding a reference to that view and might it be being released and zeroed?

Comment: @GaryMakin I changed it to `@IBOutlet var noBookmarkView: UIView!` and it still has the same problem.

Comment: That was my only guess, sorry.

Comment: @GaryMakin It's all good. Thanks! Hopefully someone can figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild? Sometimes just need to clean and everything work properly

Comment: @t4nhpt Just did, same problem

Comment: Is `filteredView` a custom view in Xib file? If yes, go to that xib file and check if any outlet/action is broken.

Comment: @t4nhpt No. `filteredView` isn't in the storyboard at all. I'm trying to do it all through Swift code (init and setting details in `viewDidLoad`)

Comment: For the wrong error line, I think it should be fixed if you clean, then reopen Xcode. And try to implement `heightForHeader` method to provide height of the header.

Comment: @t4nhpt I'm not sure quite how to do that. Maybe write an answer with an example of how to change it to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide header via the `dataSource` of the `UITableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return self.filteredView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 25
}
```

Comment: Great! That worked. I commented out section 2 and added that code. How can I make it so it only displays the header if `self.idsb.count != self.ids.count`?

Comment: You can check in the `viewForHeaderInSection`, and return nil if you don't want to display header. You may need to return height = 0 in the `heightForHeaderInSection`, too

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!!